# How use Jquery Save Cookie inthe browser when click button window reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

how use jquery cookie 
 it is save browser when windown reload...

Html

```
     <span class="switchone">setCookeOne</span> //click create cookie (name,value)
     <span class="switchtwo">setCookeOne</span>//click create cookie (name,value)
```

Jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("span.switchone").click(function () {
        setNewCookie('name', "cobra");
       location.reload();
    });
     $("span.switchtwo").click(function () {
       setNewCookie('name', "snake");
       location.reload();
    });
 });
    function setNewCookie(name, value) {
       var date = new Date();
       date.setTime(date.getTime() + ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 ));
       $.removeCookie(name);
       $.cookie(name, value, {path: '/', expires: date });
    }
```

Comment: try with this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: Your code looks fine, what is the problem with it?

Comment: but Cookie not found when browser refresh . how use..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have not used:`jquery.cookie.js`.add this file to your code.

you can find it here:`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js`

try with this:

```
 <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/src/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">


 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("span.switchone").click(function () {
        setNewCookie('name', "cobra");
       location.reload();
    });
     $("span.switchtwo").click(function () {
       setNewCookie('name', "snake");
       location.reload();
    });
 });
    function setNewCookie(name, value) {
       var date = new Date();
       date.setTime(date.getTime() + ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 ));

       $.removeCookie(name);
       $.cookie(name, value, {path: '/', expires: date });
    }
  </script>

  <span class="switchone">setCookeOne</span> //click create cookie (name,value)
     <span class="switchtwo">setCooketwo</span>//click create cookie (name,value)
```